# How to deal with multiple optional fields in jq?

Tags: jq

I have JSON objects that can contain different fields.

```
{
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "optionalA": "d"
  }
}
{
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "optionalB": "Z"
  }
}
```

In this example, the object can have the field optionalA or optionalB.

I want to filter on both if they are present. My command looks like this:

```
jq 'select(
  (.object.optionalA // empty | contains("d")) 
  or 
  (.object.optionalB // empty | contains("Z"))
)'
```

But this gives me only the result of the first filter, while the second seems ignored.
Why is this not working, and how can I filter on the respective key that's present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contains` requires a string as input. With `empty`, however, you eliminate the input entirely. You could change your approach using the empty string as void input:

```bash
select(
  (.object.optionalA // "" | contains("d")) 
  or 
  (.object.optionalB // "" | contains("Z"))
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XnqTKlg9Glv)

Or use the alternative operator `//` also instead of the boolean operator `or`, so in case of `empty` the next expression can be evaluated:

```bash
select(
  (.object.optionalA // empty | contains("d")) 
  //
  (.object.optionalB // empty | contains("Z"))
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FMd9o_PmZ8J)

Another way could be using `has` to query the presence of a field:

```bash
select(
  (.object | has("optionalA") and (.optionalA | contains("d")))
  or
  (.object | has("optionalB") and (.optionalB | contains("Z")))
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oZ2SBbEv39U)

Yet another to use the error suppression operator `?` to handle the case of absent fields:

```bash
select(
  .object | (.optionalA | contains("d")?) // (.optionalB | contains("Z")?)
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/g4NqSKxhjY0)

Output

```json
{
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "optionalA": "d"
  }
}
{
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "optionalB": "Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed explanation!